# Translating WinForms Drawing Code to Xamarin.Forms with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, translation

I have a WinForms application with drawing code that I'm trying to translate to Xamarin.Forms using SkiaSharp for cross-platform compatibility. I'm specifically having trouble with the following part of the code, which involves drawing lines and ellipses:

Original WinForms Code:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < mark.Count)
    {
        switch (mark[index])
        {
            case 0:
                int ind = 0;
                if (!inout)
                {
                    for (int i = -255; i < 256; i += 50)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255 - Math.Abs(i), Color.Yellow), 1), new Point(mark[index + 1] + ind, 0), new Point(mark[index + 1] + ind++, pictureBox1.Height));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = -255; i < 256; i += 50)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(Math.Abs(i), Color.Yellow), 1), new Point(mark[index + 1] + ind, 0), new Point(mark[index + 1] + ind++, pictureBox1.Height));
                    }
                }
                index += 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                ind = 0;
                if (!inout)
                {
                    for (int i = -255; i < 256; i += 50)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255 - Math.Abs(i), Color.Blue), 1), new Point(0, mark[index + 1] + ind), new Point(pictureBox1.Width, mark[index + 1] + ind++));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = -255; i < 256; i += 50)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(Math.Abs(i), Color.Blue), 1), new Point(0, mark[index + 1] + ind), new Point(pictureBox1.Width, mark[index + 1] + ind++));
                    }
                }
                index += 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                ind = 0;
                int id = 1;
                if (!inout)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 50)
                    {
                        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255 - i, Color.Red), 1), mark[index + 1] + ind - id, mark[index + 1] + ind + 1 - id, 2 * id, 2 * id);
                        id++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 50)
                    {
                        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(i, Color.Red), 1), mark[index + 1] + ind - id, mark[index + 1] + ind + 1 - id, 2 * id, 2 * id);
                        id++;
                    }
                }
                index += 3;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My Attempted Xamarin.Forms with SkiaSharp Code:

```
using (SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e = /* ... */)
{
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < mark.Count)
        {
            switch (mark[index])
            {
                case 0:
                    DrawLines(canvas, paint, mark[index + 1], 0, true);
                    index += 2;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    DrawLines(canvas, paint, 0, mark[index + 1], false);
                    index += 2;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    DrawEllipses(canvas, paint, mark[index + 1], mark[index + 2]);
                    index += 3;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void DrawLines(SKCanvas canvas, SKPaint paint, float x, float y, bool horizontal)
{
    int ind = 0;
    int step = horizontal ? pictureBox1.Height : pictureBox1.Width;
    int colorStep = horizontal ? 255 : 0;

    for (int i = -255; i < 256; i += 50)
    {
        paint.Color = new SKColor((byte)(colorStep + (horizontal ? Math.Abs(i) : 0)), 0, (byte)(colorStep + (horizontal ? 0 : Math.Abs(i))), 255);
        if (horizontal)
        {
            canvas.DrawLine(x + ind, 0, x + ind, step, paint);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.DrawLine(0, y + ind, step, y + ind, paint);
        }
        ind++;
    }
}

private void DrawEllipses(SKCanvas canvas, SKPaint paint, float x, float y)
{
    int ind = 0;
    int id = 1;
    int colorStep = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 50)
    {
        paint.Color = new SKColor((byte)(255 - colorStep), 0, (byte)colorStep, 255);
        canvas.DrawOval(new SKRect(x + ind - id, y + ind + 1 - id, x + ind - id + 2 * id, y + ind + 1 - id + 2 * id), paint);
        id++;
        ind++;
        colorStep += 50;
    }
}
```

I'm facing challenges in ensuring that the translation is accurate and effective. Any insights, suggestions, or improvements on my SkiaSharp code would be greatly appreciated!